# Is there a way to restrict access to aws services to get acces only on a specific website using javascript?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I have have a static HTML website where it is stored on AWS S3 ,  html page and javascript files and everything. The Website is using javascript to connect to DynamoDB database to fetch some data. To Access the DynamoDB database I use  AWS Cognito Identity Pool with Unauthenticated role. An example is a current weather site showing the results of temperature of today each hour that I uploaded to the database.

How can I restrict access to the DynamoDB results for the website only so if example if someone copies the javascript file and run the queries it wont show because its not on the website. If my website is for example [www.sanfernandoweather.com](http://www.sanfernandoweather.com) and someone copy the javascript file and put it on [www.weathersaf.com](http://www.weathersaf.com) it will not show the results

Comment: Who are you trying to protect yourself against? Anyone with a keyboard or people who know what they're doing?

Comment: anybody . I just want to restrict the results to only be available on my domain .I got ads on my website to help pay my hardware that logs temperature every hour . I do not mind people see the daily temperature on my website but if someone copy my javascript file and put it on their website it use my dynamodb table reads and that cost me money

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea ... don't give the webpage access to the DynamoDB table at all. Instead, simply write the weather info to JSON files in your S3 bucket and have the web page retrieve those instead.

You can create/update these JSON files dynamically as a result of updates to the DynamoDB weather table, via DynamoDB Streams and a simple Lambda function.

Also, consider putting CloudFront in front of this site and restrict bucket access to the OAI of your CloudFront distribution. You may have to invalidate caching on certain content when you make your weather updates.

Comment: This looks good I will try it and see if it works